# CMake : how to have CPack put all component files into a single directory?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm making an NSIS installer for Windows. I want the DLLs to be in the same directory as the executable, so that Windows can find the DLLs.

Any clean solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by first setting the destination folder for libraries to the destination folder for executables (see [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/module/GNUInstallDirs.html)) :

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
```

An second, by setting the type to `LIB` in subsequent `install()` commands :

```
install(DIRECTORY ${COMPILER_PROGRAM_DIRECTORY}/
    TYPE LIB
    COMPONENT libraries
    FILES_MATCHING
        PATTERN "libgcc*.dll"
        PATTERN "libstdc++*.dll"
        PATTERN "libwinpthread*.dll"
    )
```

The `LIB` type tells CPack to copy the files to the library directory set earlier.
With the combination of the two, the executable and the DLLs all end up in the same `bin/` subdirectory.